# How to set width of UITableView header view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

Is there any way to set the width of a UITableView section header view to something less than the full width of the UITableView? Now matter how wide I set the view returned by tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:, the header view is stretched to the width of the UITableView.

Here is my code:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  UIView *label = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
  return label;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ., if i have understood your question this will surely work for you

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 60)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIView *label = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [headerView addSubview:label];
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both responders. I'm clicking Bala's answer because his approach solved my problem. Strictly speaking, however, the returned headerView is still getting stretched across the tableview, which becomes apparent if you change its background color to red. I'm still curious why this happens, but at least I can put the finishing touches on my app now.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    int aSection = [[self.sectionsToDisplay objectAtIndex:section] integerValue];

   if([[self.groupHeadings objectAtIndex:aSection] isEqualToString:@""])

        return nil;

    return [self.groupHeadings objectAtIndex:aSection];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: return a `UIView` which contains nothing but your desired header view, while giving your headerView the UIViewAutoresizing property flexible right margin, so it won't scale with it's superview (or maybe flexible left margin, or both, depending on what loomk you want ;]).

Comment: Can you post some code? You must have made an error, there is no way the solution i described could fail.